# Remove whitespace at the end of a group

Tags: regex, whitespace

I have a string such:

```
1234-A description-987-456
```

I was able to remove White spaces at the end of the string but not in the middle (just after the description)

```
1234-A description    -987-456
```

Of course a solution would be to use a first Regex to Split groups and then remove last space using such regex: `(.*)(\s*)` replacing the 2. group by EMPTY.

But I do not find such solution elegant enough...

My try was:

```
(.)(\d{3})-(.+)(\s*)-(\d{3})\s*-\s*(\d+)
```

but without success.

[Regex examples](http://regex101.com/r/dC0iQ0).

Comment: You should consider starting to mark the answers which worked for you as [accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) :)

Answer (score 1):

Just make the `.+` lazy (i.e. `.+?`), otherwise it will consume all the spaces as well, and not leave anything for `\s*` (with a lazy quantifier, it will consume as few characters as possible).

Also, you can remove the brackets around the `\s*` and make the replacement `\1...\2...\3...\4...\5` instead.

```
(.)(\d{3})-(.+?)\s*-(\d{3})\s*-\s*(\d+)
```

Though if you want to just remove the spaces as depicted, you can remove most of the brackets:

Replace:

```
(.\d{3}-.+?)\s*(-\d{3}\s*-\s*\d+)
```

With:

```
\1\2
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

Search: `\s+-`
Replace: `-`

Comment: you may need to add `-\s+` with `|`

Comment: @jkshah: Sorry, I don't get you. What do you mean?

Comment: your solution will only trim trailing spaces before '-'. I think we will need to trim leading spaces also after `-`. e.g. what if `abc-    xyz-pqr`

Comment: @jkshah: It's not said that leading spaces must be removed.

Comment: yeah, que doesn't mention that. I didn't notice. just thought in general terms. Yours should work fine then